# Need to build new login page with my new user (customer) table in same database

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I need to built a customer database in WordPress with my own login page.
What I need is if I can use the same wp-login.php but can able to change the table for users to my desired table in the same database to check for the username and password.

I have made a plugin to cover all the requirements I need with regard to my customer. Only thing I need is to authenticate user in proper way and all the authentication, password recovery, SSL etc options are available.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a separate user table? Why not just create a custom table with all the extra info you need to store, and then link that table to the Wordpress users table via their user ID? This way you can store all the custom data you want, but still be able to fully utilize the Wordpress user account system.

Comment: I just need because I don't want my customer to look into my wordpress dashboard.

Comment: By default a user will only have the Subscriber role, they won't be able to view or edit anything in the dashboard besides their own account info.